# Mathematics of GANs (generative adversarial networks)

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions, game-theory, machine-learning, learning-roadmap

Generative Adversarial Networks were introduced in http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets and has more than [20000 citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11977070277539609369&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en).

The paper introduced key paradigm changes which require applications from modern areas of mathematics. I wanted to ask what are some the mathematics required to understand GANs as far as we know now and what are some key resources which provide accessible insight and a roadmap to learning?

Comment: For a user with such high reputation you've asked a very very broad question, whose answer I suspect you already have a substantial idea about. Maybe tell us what you think these key paradigm changes are, since you have obviously identified them, instead of linking to a paper.

Comment: The 25k citations were generated using GANs.

Answer (score 8):

• Concerning the question asked in the comment: what is the "key paradigm" of a GAN:
The basic problem that a GAN seeks to solve is to find the probability distribution $\mu$ given a finite number of samples, via iterative improvement of a trial distribution $\nu$. So we need a way to represent a probability distribution (a generator) and a way to measure differences between two distribution functions (a discriminator). The "key paradigm" of a GAN is to model both the generator and the discriminator by a neural network.

• Concerning the question in the OP on the mathematics required to understand a GAN:
[A Mathematical Introduction to Generative Adversarial Nets (GAN)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00169) (2020) is a recent overview.

Comment: The topic seems mathematically richer since it seems to be rooted in differential geometry, game theory, pdes from optimal transportation to specify a few (perhaps there are further topics). The paper fails to do justice I think.

Comment: Optimal transportation was introduced later on by use of Wasserstein distance: See this paper by WGAN. https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875

Comment: @PiyushGrover Thank you and so is it the right way to view the process and are there alternate approaches provided elsewhere? Any comments on how natural the connection to optimal transport is?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend some papers by Lars Mescheder:

- The paper [The Numerics of GANs](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6779-the-numerics-of-gans) formalizes GANs as two-player games and analyzes their training dynamics,
- the paper [Which Training Methods for GANs do actually Converge?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04406) takes this analysis further and
- the PhD thesis [Stability and Expressiveness of Deep Generative Models](http://hdl.handle.net/10900/106074) cantains a quite thorough and mathematical introduction to GANs.

Comment: All papers by Lars Mescheder https://scholar.google.de/citations?user=h2k1gL4AAAAJ&hl=de.

Comment: Historically game theory has no roots in optimal transport and converse holds too in any obvious sense. So GANs bring together disparate topics. Perhaps there are other topics in mathematics to be brought together.